# Working with arrays inside of arrays of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I'm trying to create an array of structures that has an array inside, assign some values to all the elements and print it out but only the first elements of both the arrays get initialized. I'd appreciate some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct el{
    int a[5];
    int id;
} structure;
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    structure kot[5];
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &kot[i].id);
        for(j = 0; i < 5; i++)
        kot[i].a[j] = 1;

    }
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    printf("Id: %d ", kot[i].id);
    printf(". Array inside: ");
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        printf("%d ", kot[i].a[j]);

    printf("\n");
  }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please do not edit question after getting answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for(j = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

to

```
for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
```

Comment: Good eyes, nice catch.

Comment: I just did. After I input 5 numbers for the id field the program crashes.